# How to integrate OSM with optaplanner workbench

Tags: openstreetmap, optaplanner

I have a project of employee scheduling I use optaplanner workbench and kie server.
I hav a hardscore distance between the employee and the jobs. I wante to integrate OSM with optaplanner workbench is that possible ?

Please give me suggestions or important links. thank you very much.

Comment: optaweb-vehicle-routing integrates OSM with optaplanner - but that handles the vehicle routing problem, not assigning employes to early, evening and late shifts.

Comment: thank you, Can I change the optaweb-vehicle-routing to my needs?. How to deploy workbench project on live server such as AWS LAMBDA or AZURE ? @GeoffreyDeSmet